# Do I have the right Slowly Changing Dimensions type for my version controlled tennis match database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, slowly-changing-dimension, version-control

I'm trying to version control my database using the principles of [Slowly Changing Dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension). I've opted to use Type 2 with a generation `start` and `end` column instead of datetimes.

In a simplified example I have three tables:

**player:**

| player_key | player_id | country_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |  |

**tournament:**

| tournament_key | tournament_id | surface_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |  |

**tennis_match:**

| match_id | tournament_key | player_key_p1 | player_key_p2 | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 |  |

I now want to extract all the matches and their respective tournament and player data to run some analysis on it. If I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    match_id,
    tournament_key,
    player_key_p1,
    player_key_p2,
    t.surface_id,
    p1.country_id,
    p2.country_id
FROM
    tennis_match AS m
        JOIN
    player AS p1 ON p1.player_key = m.player_key_p1
        JOIN
    player AS p1 ON p1.player_key = m.player_key_p1
        JOIN
    tournament AS t ON t.tournament_key = m.tournament_key
```

This gives me:

| match_id | tournament_key | player_key_p1 | player_key_p2 | surface_id | p1_country_id | p1_country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

The issue I'm facing is that the `surface_id` and `p1_country_id` change part way through the matches because, well, they changed part way through the matches. However, for the purposes of my analysis at `match_id = 4` I should be using the values of the latest versions of `player` and `tournament`:

| match_id | tournament_key | player_key_p1 | player_key_p2 | surface_id | p1_country_id | p1_country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

So I figure that to get the data in the format I need then I'm going to need to write some reasonable complex queries (for me) to get the data in a format I want. This has got me questioning whether I have the right structure.

If I'd gone for a Type 4 approach then my queries on the non-history tables would be nice and simple. However, if I wanted to run an analysis from a point in the past I'd have to head to the history table and I reckon I'd have the same challenge as I have now. Plus I'd have the added hassle of managing history tables and having to figure out a solution for deleted records.

I did look at Type 6 but this looked like I needed to duplicate version controlled columns - one to have a `current_state` and `historic_state`. As some of the version controlled tables have hundreds of columns this didn't seem like the right approach either so I didn't review it much further.

Finally getting to my question... do I have the right data structure and just need to knuckle down on query writing or could I implement a better design?

Comment: What do "start" and "end" represent?

Comment: Hi Rick. They're generations as per the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/125900/11277108. Just shortened the names for this post.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted for the [Type 7 Hybrid Approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_7:_Hybrid%5B4%5D_-_Both_surrogate_and_natural_key) which involves placing both the `key` and `id` fields from the dimension tables into the `tennis_match` fact table. This means I can now write the following simple query to give me the latest versions of the dimension fields I was looking for:

```
SELECT 
    match_id,
    tournament_key,
    player_key_p1,
    player_key_p2,
    t.surface_id,
    p1.country_id,
    p2.country_id
FROM
    tennis_match AS m
        JOIN
    player AS p1 ON p1.player_id = m.player_id_p1 AND p1.end IS NULL
        JOIN
    player AS p2 ON p2.player_id = m.player_id_p2 AND p2.end IS NULL
        JOIN
    tournament AS t ON t.tournament_id = m.tournament_id AND t.end IS NULL
```